# Remove duplicates in a CSV document using Notepad++

Tags: csv, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and I am trying to remove duplicates...

```
apple, green, supplier
banana, yellow, supplier
grapes, geen, supplier
apple, red, supplier
apple, brown, supplier
grapefruit, yellow, supplier
```

I would like to keep just the first instance of apple so the end result would look like this

```
apple, green, supplier
banana, yellow, supplier
grapes, geen, supplier
grapefruit, yellow, supplier
```

Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have it in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Choose the Mark tab.
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Find what: `^apple`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to check `Bookmark line`
- Click on <kbd>Mark All</kbd>

[image]

- Click to the first instance of apple to clear the first mark.
- Select from the menu Search > Bookmark > Remove Bookmarked Lines.
- Ready ...